# Having a hard time calculating totals Javascript

Tags: javascript, points

I cant seem to figure out why I cant calculate the points and keep them for each user totals.. Any suggestions? Please help. I was able to build this game using prompts etc.. but trying to bring it to life in a browser has been a challenge..

Here is the code:

```
function getName() {
  var name = document.getElementById('fName').value;
  // console.log(name);
  $(".greetingPlayer").append("<h3 class='greeting'>Greetings " + name + "!</h3><br><h4>Please choose from the following Weapons...</h4>");
  $(".statsA").css("display", "none");
}

var userChoice;

function choices(weapon) {
  userChoice = weapon;
  // console.log(userChoice);
  $(".greetingPlayer").append("<h4 class='userChoice'>Users Choice : " + userChoice + "!</h4>");
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
  if (computerChoice <= 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }
  // console.log(computerChoice);
  $(".greetingPlayer").append("<h4 class='computerChoice'>Computers Choice : " + computerChoice + "!</h4>");

  function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    var playing = true;
    var human = 0;
    var comp = 0;
    while (playing) {
      if (choice1 === choice2) {
        console.log("The result is a tie!");
        human = score;
        comp = score;
      } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
          console.log("rock wins!");
        } else {
          console.log("paper wins!");
        }
      } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
          console.log("paper wins!");
        } else {
          console.log("scissors wins!");
        }
      } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
          console.log("scissors wins!");
        } else {
          console.log("rock wins!");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("That's not an option! Do it over " + name + " and try again!");
      }
      playing = false;
    }
    console.log("human : " + human);
    console.log("comp : " + comp);
    var numpoints = 0;
    function points() {
      if (++score >= str.length) {
        numpoints++;
        document.getElementByClassName("points").textContent = "Score: " + numpoints;
      }
    }
  }
  compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
}
// $(".greetingPlayer").append("<h4 class='userWeapon'> " + name + "! You win!</h4>");
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense. Why do you compare the score to a str variable that is not even initialized ? Plus, you are never calling the points function, so I don't see how your score is supposed to get updated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, my scope was all wrong and I have no idea why I was attempting to add a loop on the bottom. However this seemed to solve...

```
                function getName(){
                var name = document.getElementById('fName').value;
                // console.log(name);
                $(".greetingPlayer").append("<h3 class='greeting'>Greetings " + name + "!</h3><br><h4>Please choose from the following Weapons...</h4>");
                $(".statsA").css("display", "none");
            }

                    // Here we declare a variable to represent a User's Choice outside of the function scope
                    var userChoice;
                    var computerChoice;

                    //These variables are created to keep score and are declared w/ zero for addition.
                    var compScore = 0;
                    var userScore = 0;

            // Here we declare a function to compare a userChoice vs compChoice
            var choices = function(weapon){
                userChoice = weapon;
                  // console.log(userChoice);

                computerChoice = Math.random();
              // console.log(computerChoice);

              if (computerChoice <= 0.34) {
                computerChoice = "rock";
              } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
                computerChoice = "paper";
              } else {
                computerChoice = "scissors";
              } 

                    $(".toolChoice").html(" " + userChoice + "!");
                // console.log(computerChoice);
                $(".toolChoiceB").html(" " + computerChoice + "!");

                function compare(choice1, choice2){

                    if(choice1 === choice2){
                        console.log("The result is a tie!");
                    }else if(choice1 === "rock"){
                        if(choice2 === "scissors"){
                            console.log("rock wins!");
                            userScore++;
                        }else{
                            console.log("paper wins!");
                            compScore++;
                        }
                    }else if(choice1 === "paper"){
                        if(choice2 === "rock"){
                            console.log("paper wins!");
                            userScore++;
                        }else{
                            console.log("scissors wins!");
                            compScore++;
                        }
                    }else if(choice1 === "scissors"){
                        if(choice2 === "paper"){
                            console.log("scissors wins!");
                            userScore++;
                        }else{
                            console.log("rock wins!");
                            compScore++;
                        }
                    }else{
                        console.log("That's not an option! Do it over " 
                            + name + " and try again!");
                    }
                }
            // end of compare function

            // compare function called
            compare(userChoice, computerChoice);

                // This consoles the score, use this as a start point for displaying the score. 
                // console.log("human : " + userScore);
                // console.log("comp : " + compScore);

                // This jQuery displays the score for each party

                // This is the score for Humans
                $('.scoreA').html(" " + userScore);
            // This is the score for Computers
                $('.scoreB').html(" " + compScore);
            }
```